# OpenGL GLKit : rendering different size vertices objects together. ios opengl draw call exceeded array buffer bounds

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I very much doubt anyone can help me on this but hey ho.

I have a 3D framework I have been working on where most things in the world are cubes (36 vertices).

I followed this great tutorial about bringing blender objects in to OpenGL : http://www.raywenderlich.com/48293/how-to-export-blender-models-to-opengl-es-part-1

I brought the cube in and all was good, I then tried to bring a sphere in, cube, cylinder etc and it blows up with
**ios opengl draw call exceeded array buffer bounds**

I know the objects are fine as they work with the demo app but that only renders 1 object and has no binding of arrays and vertex's etc

Anyway

I am sure this code is junk but I have tried everything

```
- (void)setupSphere;
{

    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);
//////
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(&sphereVertices), &sphereVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
////
    glGenBuffers(1, &_position);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _position);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(spherePositions),spherePositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
////
    glGenBuffers(1, &_texture);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _texture);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(sphereTexels),sphereTexels, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
////
    glGenBuffers(1, &_normal);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _normal);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(sphereNormals),sphereNormals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//////
//    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);

    // Positions
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _position);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, spherePositions);

    // Texels
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _texture);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, sphereTexels);

    // Normals
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _normal);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, sphereNormals);

    //glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
}

- (void)drawSphere:(float)eyeOffset
{
    // Calculate the per-eye model view matrix:
    GLKMatrix4 temp = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(eyeOffset, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    GLKMatrix4 eyeBaseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(temp, self.baseModelViewMatrix);

    if (self.isTransparant)
    {
        glEnable (GL_BLEND);
        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    }

    if (self.textureInfo)
    {
        glBindTexture(self.textureInfo.target, self.textureInfo.name);
    }


    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glUseProgram(_program);

    self.modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(self.position.x,self.position.y, self.position.z );//(float)x, (float)y, -1.5f)
    self.modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(self.modelViewMatrix, self.scale.x, self.scale.y, self.scale.z);

    //rotation +=0.01;
    self.modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(self.modelViewMatrix,rotation, 0.0 ,0.0 ,1.0);
    self.modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(eyeBaseModelViewMatrix, self.modelViewMatrix);

    GLKMatrix3 normalMatrix = GLKMatrix3InvertAndTranspose(GLKMatrix4GetMatrix3(self.modelViewMatrix), NULL);
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(self.projectionMatrix, self.modelViewMatrix);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
    glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, normalMatrix.m);

    _colorSlot = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "color");
    GLfloat color[] = {
        self.color.x, self.color.y, self.color.z, self.color.a};
    glUniform4fv(_colorSlot, 1, color);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sphereVertices);

    if (self.isTransparant)
    {
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use a VAO with client vertex arrays. This is not supported. Quoting from the [extension spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_vertex_array_object.txt):

> - Should a vertex array object be allowed to encapsulate client
>      vertex arrays?
>
>   RESOLVED: No. The OpenGL ES working group agreed that compatibility
>      with OpenGL and the ability to to guide developers to more
>      performant drawing by enforcing VBO usage were more important than
>      the possibility of hurting adoption of VAOs.

If you want to use a VAO, you will need to enable the VBO code that seems mostly present in your code, but currently commented out.

Comment: If you have any idea how to fix this in actual code you would make me a very happy man, what lines should I in comment and comment out. I was working on this at 3 am

Comment: Uncomment the second set of `glBindBuffer` calls. For the `glVertexAttribPointer` calls following them, change the last argument to `0`, since that becomes an offset into the buffer once you have a VBO bound.

Comment: You sir, rock!,  thank you so much for your help.  Honestly you rock!